# LINQ DAL Generator

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, code-generation

Is there any software or provider or framework exist that able us to generate DAL layer with Linq To SQL?
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx)

Comment: i did not find download link . please put download link. thanks.

Comment: you don't need to download anything. SqlMetal is a command tool. you can simply run it via visual studio command prompt. start->Microsoft Vusual Studio[your version]->Visual Studio Tools->Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010). then just type sqlmetal.exe to get help for arguments.

Comment: From the doc: The SQLMetal file is included in the Windows SDK that is installed with Visual Studio. By default, the file is located at drive:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vn.nn\bin.

Comment: a simple command could be something like this:
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\sqlmetal.exe" /server:localhost /database:myDataBase /user:sa /password:123/dbml:myDataBase.dbml /namespace:DAL /context:myDataContext /language:c# /provider:SQL2000 /pluralize 
this command simply creates .dbml file for myDataBase(sql server 2000) on localhost. the pluralize switch forces sqlmetal to create plural names for tables.

Comment: i don't have any more option ?